# If <option> is selected, run query again

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a dropdown  named Category, the options are populated by a PHP script that queries for category names in a MySQL table.

Next to it, I have a dropdown  named Subcategory, the options are also populated by a PHP script that queries for subcategory names in a MySQL table.

I'd like to re-run the subcategory query to change the values of the Subcategory dropdown, based on which category has been selected from the Category dropdown.

And I don't want the page to refresh, so I'm thinking jquery might have some use here?

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://remysharp.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/01/select.html

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var select = $("#select-element");
    select.change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url: "url-of-your-php-script",
            data: {
                'data-name' : 'data-to-send'               
            }
            success : function(returned){
               // Append variable  results to select..
            }                
        });            
    });
});​
```

Comment: The seems right, and I can get jquery/ajax to send the selected values, however, how do i return the results of the query into the dropdown? I'm guessing success: function(returned) should change the subcategory dropdown, but should i return $subcat1, $subcat2, etc, or format the subcategories into an html string in the external php, shove that into a single variable, and return that?

Comment: To get your php array ready for javascript use JSON_encode, then simply iterate through it and append it to your select item.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you shouldn't use jQuery(or any other framework for that matter), unless you're already downloading it on a page.  While your browser is downloading the scripts and libraries (of which, jQuery is probably going to be the largest), the rest of your page can't execute.  I don't know why, but it won't download images, load iframes, nothing.

You can make an [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) request to download the new content.  Be careful, as this means you're essentially writing a webservice with access to your database, so make sure to validate inputs on both the server and in the javascript, as well as developing some kind of security for drop/delete actions.

Here's a [native javascript tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp) for Ajax, but if you're hell bent on AJAX, you can [use it](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

The basic goal is this:

1. Write a web page that takes as arguments the new parameters for your query,
   then
2. call it with AJAX, and
3. use the returned information to re-populate your drop down.

I implore you to be sure you understand AJAX in native code before you let jQuery do it all for you.  Even if you choose to use the jQuery framework in the end, it will help you when debugging, upgrading, and reusing this code.

Comment: Please do not link to w3schools. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with linking to W3 schools.  I admit I haven't been through this entire tutorial, so I can't necessarily vouch for it, but I find their site to be an incredibly useful starting point for new concepts.  It's usually close enough to right to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes your right you have to use Jquery $.ajax() or $.post() function specifically.
2. The subcategory drop down should listen to the parent categories on change event. In Jquery you can do that using.

   $('#parent').change(function(){

   ```
          var parent = $(this).val();
          // Remove current subcategory options
          $('#child').children().remove();
          // AJAX POST
          $.ajax({

            type:'POST',

       data: 'parent='+parent,

       url: 'process.php',

       success: function(data){

                   // Fill the subcategory with new options using jquery each method 

                }
              });

       });
   ```